Test users keep getting disabled within 24h of creation
Are there reserved/suggested names that should be used to distinguish a LinkedIn test profile? Any I create get shut down within 24h before I can do my developement and testing on the API.
I wasn't able to find a recent/answered thread on this, but see others used to experience it as well. I see they are allowed, but can't seem to keep mine active.
Thanks for any advice.
I tried multiple users, different computers and emails. Some with "generic" names, some I had colleagues "friend" but no luck.
